# Base levels for a factor variable in Stata with interaction

Tags: stata

I'm having trouble defining the base of a factor variable in an interaction between variables. (wooldridge selection correction)

I want to define qt = 179 as the base for the variable qt in this panel regression

```
xtreg `x' b179.qt#c._imrb [pw=ww] if sel==1 `sam`g'', fe vce(cluster ids)
```

But apparently this doesn't work with interactions between variables, because in the result qt=176 (minimum value for qt) is the base.

It doesn't happen when I use the ## operator instead of # (b179.qt##c._imrb), but I only want to include the interaction between qt and _imrb, but not include each variable by itself.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If I follow this  you need to work with `qt` - 176 or `qt` - 179, depending on which detail is correct.